# nokiax reports java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made

Tags: android, android-fonts, nokiax

NokiaX reports this exception on fonts used.

I have a library project under which I have `assets/fonts/Roboto-*.ttf` files. I have gone through the other questions on this topic, all of them hint at spelling check, or folder check (should be under `assets/fonts`). None of them seem to be the issue. This code works well with Android.

What am I missing here ?

```
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.taxeeta.nokiax/com.taxeeta.SplashScreen}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2067)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4807)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:559)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at com.taxeeta.support.FontUtils.setRobotoFont(FontUtils.java:14)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at com.taxeeta.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:165)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5180)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
05-04 10:19:49.430: E/Crittercism(17208):   ... 11 more
```

Comment: I suppose its because the Nokia X does not use Roboto, its using Nokia pure font instead. The font is neearly 100 % compatile, but indeed its not named roboto.

Comment: Nope, was not because of that. App works well with Roboto font now.

Comment: Mr downvoter, please share a reason for the downvote ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found this in the android docs. Cool. I moved the fonts folder out of the library project and into the application project and all worked fine.

> **Library projects cannot include raw assets**
>
> The tools do not support the use of raw asset files (saved in the assets/ directory) in a library project. Any asset resources used by an application must be stored in the assets/ directory of the application project itself. However, resource files saved in the res/ directory are supported.

Comment: Please upvote my question. Some dumbwit downvoted it.

Comment: You are champ boss. Saved my life. Struggled from 2 days and finally your solution helped me.

Comment: Anytime dude, anytime.